# Keep authentication between 2 applications with Keycloak SSO

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, jhipster, keycloak

I have 2 JHipster apps running each on one subdomain (app1.domain.tld & app2.domain.tld).

In both apps, users login through Keycloak. The sequence is as such :

1. Angular app sends /authenticate request with credentials to Keycloak
2. In case of successful response returns a authentication cookie
3. POST request is is sent to Jhipster backend app that generates JSessionID cookie
4. JSessionID is then used for every request to backed app.

What would be the best way to automatically login user (without asking username & password) if they are already logged in one of the apps of the domain (*.domain.tld) ?

I tried to use the JSessionID as a global token before understanding it only works on the app it was generated on...

Maybe catching Keycloak authentication cookie (returned at step 2) and authenticating on second application would do the trick ?

From what I saw while testing, after being authenticated on first app, when I go to the second one, Angular 401 HTTP interceptor redirects to keycloak login page with a session token. Thus at that time Keycloak should see that I'm already logged in and should redirect me to home page of my second app.

Am I right ?

Comment: Any solution?  I am also working with the same requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The [javascript adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_adapter) solve this by creating an [iframe](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/js/src/main/resources/login-status-iframe.html) that's loaded from the authentication server.

From the [keycloak docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#session-status-iframe):

> **Session Status iframe**
>
> By default, the JavaScript adapter creates a hidden iframe that is used to detect if a Single-Sign Out has occurred. This does not require any network traffic, instead the status is retrieved by looking at a special status cookie. This feature can be disabled by setting checkLoginIframe: false in the options passed to the init method.You should not rely on looking at this cookie directly. Its format can change and it’s also associated with the URL of the Keycloak server, not your application.

The success callback of init function has a parameter that gives the authentication status of the user.

```
<script src="keycloak.js"></script>
<script>
    var keycloak = Keycloak();
    keycloak.init().success(function(authenticated) {
        alert(authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated');
    }).error(function() {
        alert('failed to initialize');
    });
</script>
```

If the user is authenticated redirect the user to the login page, since the user is already authenticated there is no need to input the login credentials again. The adapter can handle this automatically if it's initialized with the onload option `check-sso`

For more details on the inner workings of the javascript adapter, the source can be found [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/js/src/main/resources/keycloak.js)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not seem to work in my case. The problem seems to be between jHipster and Keycloak as when I generate 2 standard JHipster applications and connect them to my keycloak instance, only 1 app can be connected at a time. When I connect to the other app, the first app is disconnected

Comment: Are you using the same client for both applications? What do you mean with "disconnected" ? @Biologeek

Comment: Yes I'm using same clientId and clientSecret for both apps. Both are set in Spring application.yml. 
What I mean by disconnected is that when I come back to first application where I was logged in, after connecting to second app, REST calls to backend result in 401 HTTP error in first app.

Comment: I would advise to [configure](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_clients) _different_ clients for each app in keycloak.

Comment: Same result with two different clientId and clientSecret... It seems like only one connection per user is allowed in the same realm

Comment: You can have many sessions with multiple clients, no limits there. Check the logs for you application and keycloak and find out why your application is responding with 401.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the cookie name generated on the client where token information is stored. In this way, using app2 will not invalidate the token of app1 because it will use a different name. Maybe there is a better way to accomplish this in a SSO environment but it works for me.

Change `application.yaml` by adding `server.servlet.session.cookie.name` entry with the new cookie name:

```
server:
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        http-only: true
        name: JSESSIONID_APP1
```