# Authentification of 2 APPs with the same Keycloak (SSO)

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, jhipster, keycloak

I need your help for a special usecase, I searched on the internet but didn't found anything that would mach my case.
I'm new to keycloak so it may be something easy to do but I failed to resolve it :

I have two apps with spring boot security which are connected to the same keycloack. Front-end of both was generated by JHIPSTER.
Let's call them app1 and app2.

**1st case** :
I'm connected to app1 and app2 from the same browser, it works well, I can request app1 from app2.

**2nd case** :
I'm connected to app2 only and try to request app1: I got 401 response.

My question is why this is happenning while app2 is using the same keycloak as app1 ?
I tried to use same and different clients but it does not change anything.

*PS: I already look into issue like this one: [Keep authentication between 2 applications with Keycloak SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53839769/keep-authentication-between-2-applications-with-keycloak-sso)
where it is explained that the use of the JSESSIONID cookie only works on the app it was generated on (that's why i think 1st case works). So I also tried to use the [Javascript adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_adapter) ... but i don't think that it will solve my problem (2nd case).*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate whether your apps are on same domain and also your KeyCloak configuration: common realm or different realms per client? You should probably have 2 clients in  same realm, check KeyCloak docs.

Comment: `I can request app1 from app2`. Please, translate this to proper technical words..

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. To give you some details, for the Keycloak i have 1 Ream ("jhipster") where i defined 2 clients ("web_app" and "web_app2"), one for each app. Client configurations are the same (Access Type: confidential, Client protocol: openid-connect, etc.)....

Comment: For the application, app1 et app2 are mono-instance application generated with Jhipster (Spring Boot + VueJS). The API services of each app is denied if you're not authenticated with the Keycloak (Spring Security). When i said "i can request app1 from app2", i want for exemple get all items (ex: articles) for the current user (ex: "Patrick"). This API service is defined in app1 and i want this information to display in app2, so i request the API Service of app1 from app2 to get that.

Comment: When i'm connected in app1 with user Patrick,i can get this information from app1 (logic) and from app2 too (with the coockie of the browser). But i want to request this API service without i have to connect first to app1 and only connect to app2 with the user Patrick.